# Making MemberQ listable in Mathematica or threading the MemberQ function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to thread `MemberQ` through a list, i.e.:

I have

```
a={{1, 9}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {4, 3}};
b= {1, 5, 2, 6};
```

Ideally I would like to have a threaded and listable `MemberQ` function `TLMemberQ` to do the following:

`TLMember[a,b]` to return `{True,True,False,False}`. How can I do that in a way that execute fastest. 
Note: Neither `Thread@MemberQ` nor `MemberQ@Thread` work. `MemberQ` attributes is `Protected`

Comment: What about `MapThread[MemberQ, {a, b}]`?

Comment: @Heike answered simultaneously again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
MapThread[MemberQ, {a, b}]
```

?

See what it does like this:

```
Trace[
    MapThread[MemberQ, {a, b}],
    MemberQ
]
(*
{{MemberQ[{1,9},1],True},
 {MemberQ[{2,5},5],True},
 {MemberQ[{3,1},2],False},
 {MemberQ[{4,3},6],False}}
*)
```

Comment: :great answer! just what i was looking for

Answer (score 3):

`MemberQ[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{a, b}]`

Comment: Or `MemberQ[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Thread[{a, b}]` to take the OP approach